# Class with a generic class composition that implement IComparable, C#

Tags: c#, generics, interface, icomparable

I want to create a PQ that uses a separate class called Key to store the values that can take in a generic type, I also want to restrict the types to string and int. I will need to implement the IComparable interface. How do I do this?

I am getting a bunch of errors regarding the type arguments, I have put comments in my code to show where the errors are.

How do I implement something like this?

```
public class MaxPQ<T>
{
    private Key[] pq; //Key requires 1 type argument
    private int N;

    public MaxPQ(int capacity)
    {
        pq = new Key[capacity + 1]; //Requires Type arguments
    }


    private void exch<T>(int i, int j)
    {
        Key<T> temp = pq[i]; //Cannot be used as a type
        pq[i] = pq[j];
        pq[j] = temp;
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Key class for value in the Priority Queue
    /// </summary>
    private class Key<T> where T : IComparable<int, string> //IComparable cannot be used with type argument
    {
        T _value;

        public Key(T value)
        {
            _value = value;
        }


        public int CompareTo(Key obj) //Required type arguments
        {
            if (obj == null) return 1;

            return;
        }


    }
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? By saying `where T : IComparable<int, string>` you are trying to restrict your `Key<T>` to only be generic of type `IComparable<int, string>`. Your `private Key[] pq` is trying to declare a type of `class Key` when it doesn't exist, but you can pass in the type parameter from `MaxPQ<T>` to a `private Key<T>[]` if you would like?

Comment: I am trying to restrict the Key to be only of type string and int, and in the MaxPQ class, have an array of this key class that I can compare the values of each of with

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it:

```
public class Key<T>
{
    public T Value { get; private set; }
    private Key( ) { }
    public static Key<T> Make(T inVal)
    {
        var inT = inVal.GetType();
        if (inT != typeof(int) && inT != typeof(string))
            throw new TypeAccessException("Wrong type");
        return new Key<T> {Value = inVal};
    }
}
```

to use it:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myKey = Key<string>.Make("StringKeyValue");
        Console.WriteLine($"String Key is {myKey.Value}");
        var otherKey = Key<int>.Make(23);
        Console.WriteLine($"integer Key is {otherKey.Value}");
        try {var badTypKey = Key<DateTime>.Make(DateTime.Now); }
        catch (TypeAccessException x)
        { Console.WriteLine($" Got TypeAccessException {x.Message}"); }
        Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to terminate.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
    public class MaxPQ<T> : IComparable<MaxPQ<T>>
    {
        static SortedDictionary<T, MaxPQ<T>> dict = new SortedDictionary<T, MaxPQ<T>>();
        private string pq;
        private int N;

        private void exch(T i, T j)
        {
            MaxPQ<T> temp = dict[i];
            dict[i] = dict[j];
            dict[j] = temp;
        }


        public int CompareTo(MaxPQ<T> obj) //Required type arguments
        {
            int results = 0;
            if (this.pq == obj.pq)
            {
                results = this.N.CompareTo(obj.N);
            }
            else
            {
                this.pq.CompareTo(obj.pq);
            }
            return results;
        }

    }
```